# Is Appengine dispatch.yaml file affecting a specific module version?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am starting to use modules in my python Google Appengine app.

I managed to test my configuration locally (on the dev server) and everything is working fine.

I want to test my changes on a side version online and didn't find a place that states whether the dispatch configuration will affect **only** my side version or my main serving version also (that's dangerous).

I know that `cron.yaml` is not a version specific file, how about `dispatch.yaml`?

Is it safe to deploy a side version with a dispatch file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Configuration Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/configuration-files):

> Optional application-level configuration files (`dispatch.yaml`,
>   `cron.yaml`, `index.yaml`, and `queue.yaml`) are included in the top
>   level app directory.

So no, you can't test a `dispatch.yaml` file change without affecting **all** versions of **all** your app's services/modules since it's an app-level configuration.

To be able to test app-level config file changes I'm using an entirely separate application as a staging environment.