# dispatch.yaml not getting updated

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I edited my dispatch.yaml and deployed on app engine using
 appcfg.py update_dispatch .

But when I go and see source code under StackDriver debug, I don't see the change.

Why the changes doesn't get reflected. But when I deploy complete app by appcfg.py update . the changes get reflected.

But in case, If I only want to update dispatch how do I do???

Comment: Hm, updating the live `dispatch.yaml` used to work just fine. Does the live app functionality see the update? Which SDK version?

Comment: I can see the updates under Dispatch Routes in Services tab but when I view Source Code from Diagnose -> Tools -> Source I don't see changes.  SDK version is Google Cloud SDK 160.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Try

> gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml

...to connect services to dispatch rules.

Answer (score 0):

While debatable, I'd say this is somehow the expected behaviour (at least from a historic prospective - even since support for multiple service/modules was added).

There is a difference between the code itself and what the code does - at least for the app-level config files: `dispatch.yaml`, `cron.yaml`, `index.yaml` and `queue.yaml`. The configurations corresponding to these files apply to the entire application, not to a single service/module. But the app code exists only in one or more service/module code repositories, there is no app-level repository (yet). So, to be version-controlled, these config files are present into one (or more) service/module code repositories.

When you're looking in StackDriver you're looking at a specific version of the service/module code containing those files and, to see a change, you need to update the respective service/module code. This is what `appcfg.py update` does. Which may or may not always update the live configurations (the behaviour!) corresponding to these configurations files, for whatever reason.

This is why each of these configuration files also has a corresponding command to update the live configuration/behaviour, which can be done independently from the updates of the service/module code in which they reside. This is what `appcfg.py update_dispatch` does - it only updates the actual Dispatch Rules of the entire app.

Related: [Is Appengine dispatch.yaml file affecting a specific module version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848486/is-appengine-dispatch-yaml-file-affecting-a-specific-module-version/40849069#40849069)

Comment: gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml in my case returns 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [500]:
  Internal Server Error.
  b'<h3>Server Error</h3><p>A server error has occurred.</p>'
Can't actually made changes on routes and my file is like the example here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml?hl=it
Need only to remove one rule, not all.