# App Engine - subdomain pointing to particular service

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, gae-module

I have two subdomains registered in my App Engine application:

- service-a.my-app.com
- service-b.my-app.com

I have added all the records (CNAME, A) on the server.

I have three services in my GAE:

- default
- service-a
- service-b

And I want each subdomain to point to the correct service. However, each time I access them, only the default service is used.

Side note: the GAE is running a flexible environment for laravel 5.4 and my dispatch.yaml (located in default service is as follows:

```
dispatch:
-url: "service-a.my-app.com/*"
 service: service-a
-url: "service-b.my-app.com/*"
 service: service-b
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `dispatch.yaml` is an app-level configuration, not a service-level one and occasionally updating the service containing it doesn't automatically update the app-level configs.

You should use the specific deployment commands for `dispatch.yaml`, executed from the directory containing the file:

- `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml` if you're using the Cloud SDK
- `appcfg.py update_dispatch .` if you're still using the GAE SDK

See also [dispatch.yaml not getting updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698229/dispatch-yaml-not-getting-updated/44737421#44737421).

The same is true for other app-level `.yaml` config files as well, which is probably one reason for each having its own update/deploy command (and also to allow deploying them independently of any particular app service. Somehow related: [Why do I need to deploy a "default" app before I can deploy multiple services in GCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360790/why-do-i-need-to-deploy-a-default-app-before-i-can-deploy-multiple-services-in/42361987#42361987)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Hope this helps someone.

GAE Standard:
I have an angular project which will load for any subdomain except one subdomain "api".
The backend is written in Go and all services are under a service named "api"

**STEP1: Setting local env**

Angular project has the following app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: F1
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: default/index.html
  upload: default/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: default
```

My service.yaml file resides in a separate directory and has the following

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1
instance_class: F1
service: api
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
  secure: always
```

My dispatch.yaml has the following

```
dispatch:
- url: "api.MYDOMAINNAME.com/*"
  service: api
//Add more subdomain : services mapping here
```

I deployed all these files using `gcloud app deploy` command

**Step 2 - Configure Custom domains in GAE.**

In GAE Console, goto `Project Settings > Custom Domains`

1. Add your domain
2. Verify your domainusing one of the methods provided by Google.
3. Update CNAME, A and AAA records in your domain service provider's DNS Settings

**Step 3 - Configure Sub Domain**

Add a subdomain `api.MYDOMAINNAME.com`

Add the CNAME in your domain service provider's settings. 
// add more subdomains if required

Add a Wildcard subdomain `*.MYDOMAINNAME.com`

Add the CNAME in your domain service provider's settings to redirect * to google.

**Finally:**

Wait for few minutes for the settings to be applied.

Now your application will redirect `MYDOMAINNAME.com, www.MYDOMAINNAME.com , *.MYDOMAINNAME.com` to the Angular code

and 
`api.MYDOMAINNAME.com` to your api service

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was really easy: You just need to map a wildcard subdomain and GAE would the use the service corresponding to the prefix.

Comment: Can you please share the exact setting in GAE?